# proof about rows and columns in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in an introductory linear algebra course, and I really need help on this question:

Prove that if $P$ and $Q$ are $n\times n$ matrices such that at least one of them has rows that don't span $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the columns of the product $PQ$ don't span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here is what I think the answer is:
$\det (PQ) = \det (P) \cdot\det (Q)$
if at least one $P$ or $Q$ has rows that don't span $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the determinant of that matrix ($P$ or $Q$, whichever satisfies the condition) must be $0$
but then $\det (PQ)$ is $0$
but then by IVT $PQ$ has columns that don't span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not very skilled at writing proofs, so I would like feedback on it! Thank you very much.

Comment: This proof works fine and is well-written too.

Comment: I suggest that you visit the page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to format your question in LaTeX. For future reference.